# C Insert into array pointer

Tags: c

I am writing a C program to insert element into an array with pointers. In my INSERT method I can't seem to add the element into the array. when I select option 4, it shows 0 number in the array.

the test case I use is as follows :

1. run the program
2. select option 1
3. Enter an array size
4. enter the element to add to the array.
5. select option 4 to display the array

```
    // Online C compiler to run C program online
    #include <stdio.h>
    #define MAX 10
    
    void initialize (int *size, int ar[]);
    void insert (int max, int *size, int ar[], int num);
    void iremove (int *size, int ar[], int num);
    void display (int size, int ar[]);
    
    
    int main ()
    {
      int option = 0;
      int num, ar[MAX], size = 0;
    
      printf ("Please select an option: \n");
      printf ("(1) Initialize the array \n");
      printf ("(2) Insert an integer \n");
      printf ("(3) Remove an integer \n");
      printf ("(4) Display the numbers stored in the array \n");
      printf ("(5) Quit \n");
    
      do
        {
            printf ("Enter your choice: \n");
            scanf ("%d", &option);
            switch (option)
            {
                case 1:
                    initialize (&size, ar);
                break;
                case 2:
                    printf ("Enter an integer: \n");
                    scanf ("%d", &num);
                    insert (MAX, &size, ar, num);
                break;
                case 3:
                break;
                case 4:
                    display(size,ar);
                break;
        default:
          break;
            }
        }
        while (option < 5);
        return 0;
    }
    
    void display (int size, int ar[])
    {
        int i;
        printf ("The %d numbers in the array: \n", size);
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf ("%d ", ar[i]);
        printf ("\n");
    }
    
    void initialize (int *size, int ar[])
    {
        int total, i, num;
        printf ("Enter the total number of integers (MAX=%d): \n", MAX);
        scanf ("%d", &total);
        (*size) = 0;
        printf ("Enter the integers: \n");
        for (i = 0; i < total; i++)
        {
            scanf ("%d", &num);
            insert (MAX, size, ar, num);
        }
    }
    
    void insert (int max, int *size, int ar[], int num)
    {
        if(*size>=MAX)
        {
            printf("Array full")
        }
        else
        {
            ar[*size] = num;
        }
    }
    
    void iremove (int *size, int ar[], int num)
    {
    /* Write your code here */
    }
```

Comment: Please format your code/post correctly.

Comment: Size should be increased after insertion.

Comment: @MikeCat How did you manage formatting it? I couldn't ..

Comment: my preview of post was formatted, but when i submitted the formatting gone..

Comment: @MikeCAT the INSERT method is being called at the INITIALIZE(), so i think in each for loop, its being called to insert

Comment: @MikeCAT could you take a look at my edited post, my nested for loop, which variable should i use to compare the value with...

Comment: @Blastfurnace you meant start a new post?

Comment: @Blastfurnace Thanks! i have removed my edit... ill post a new question..

Comment: @Blastfurnace oh man, can only do so 90 minutes later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to increment the size :

```
void insert (int max, int *size, int ar[], int num)
    {
        if(*size>=MAX)
        {
            printf("Array full")
        }
        else
        {
            ar[*size] = num;
            (*size)++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `*size++;` is wrong. It will just increment pointer and meaninglessly dereferenct the pointer. You should use `(*size)++;`.

Comment: @dspr doesnt work.. when i select option 4, it still shows "The 0 number in the array are"

Comment: what does the ( ) does?

Comment: It isolates the dereferencing from the incrementation

Comment: @BenYap Fixed code seems [working](https://wandbox.org/permlink/U8g87V7R0jrnT7UW) after adding a semicolon after `printf("Array full")`.

Comment: @MikeCAT yup. its working after adding a semicolon and adding a () to *size++

Comment: @MikeCAT btw how do i sort the int array in Ascending order?

Comment: @BenYap [`qsort()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort)

Comment: @MikeCAT can i add a loop inside my INSERT() to sort ascending as it is being added into the array?

Comment: @BenYap Yes, you can.

Comment: @MikeCAT okay gonna try a nested for loop

Comment: @dspr you have an UB for size==max

Comment: @P__J__ : do you mean in `ar[*size] = num;` ? but this is catched by the `if` statement. Otherwise I don't see where, could you explain ?

Comment: *size ==max it is UB

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest avoiding side effects in the code when possible. Use return values.

Also, try to use the correct types as well. For sizes use `size_t` defined in many headers *for example `stdio.h` or `stdlib.h`)

Your functions should be called append as you do not insert but append the value to the end of the array.

```
size_t append(size_t max, size_t size, int *array, int num)
{
    if(size < max)
    {
        array[size++] = num
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Array full");
    }
    return size;
}
```

and the call

```
size = insert(MAX, size, ar, num);
```